# How to resolve 'class must either be abstract or implement abstract' error when I call onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

The end game here is to collect user input from an autocomplete text view, split the array then send it off to another activity.  I've been trying to use getItemAtPosition to access the data at the selected position then split it and send it to another activity but 1) not sure exactly if I should be even using getItemAtPosition and I am also gettin a 'class must be abstract or implement abstract...." error on the 'public class DestinationActivity extends'...bit

code snippet:

```
public class DestinationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

AutoCompleteTextView actv;
Button bContinue;
String[] splitString;
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_destination);

    String[] airports = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.airport_array);

    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actvDestination);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,airports);
    actv.setThreshold(1);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);


    actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                /*getItemAtPosition()
                splitString = actv.getText().toString().split(":");
                splitString[0] = splitString[0].trim();
                splitString[1] = splitString[1].trim();*/
            }
        });
```

**logcat**

```
  08-20 12:08:07.969 21346-21346/com.example.alibasmaci.maral E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.alibasmaci.maral, PID: 21346
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alibasmaci.maral/com.example.alibasmaci.maral.DestinationActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                                  at com.example.alibasmaci.maral.DestinationActivity.onCreate(DestinationActivity.java:35)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 


                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-20 12:08:15.849 22158-22158/com.example.alibasmaci.maral E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.alibasmaci.maral.FlightTypeActivity.access$super
08-20 12:08:15.849 22158-22158/com.example.alibasmaci.maral W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 23 (Landroid/app/ActivityManager$TaskDescription;) in Lcom/example/alibasmaci/maral/FlightTypeActivity;
08-20 12:08:15.959 22158-22158/com.example.alibasmaci.maral W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4273: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performDestroyView ()V
08-20 12:08:15.959 22158-22158/com.example.alibasmaci.maral W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4272: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performDestroy ()V
08-20 12:08:15.969 22158-22158/com.example.alibasmaci.maral W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4273: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performDestroyView ()V
08-20 12:08:15.969 22158-22158/com.example.alibasmaci.maral W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4272: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performDestroy ()V
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Remove "implements  View.OnClickListener".

Comment: As for the exception you are getting, I think it fully goes something like `Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method`, and my best guess here: you haven't implemented `onClick(View v)` method from `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: It's a compilation error, not an exception. There is no "stacktrace". You have said your class implements  View.OnClickListener. This interface has a method onClick(View v) which you need to either add, or remove the "implements View.OnClickListener" from your class.

Comment: Remove "implements View.OnClickListener" thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove "implements View.OnClickListener" courtesy of ThePerson

Comment: How does this solve the stacktrace? You got an Index Out of Bounds exception

Comment: oh i realize there are many things wrong but i figured this question was specifically for the "Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method" errpr

Comment: That's a pretty standard Java compilation error - it's simple to fix if you understand inheritance and interface implementation